# PHP Google Calendar without command line

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I need to use google calendar on my site. 
I tested it on my local and it works:

```
require_once (load_runner::get_dir('LIBS') . "/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/vendor/autoload.php");
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
        Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)
));
/*
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}*/

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

// Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
$credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
} else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));



     // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

        // Store the credentials to disk.
        if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
        printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
    }
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
    if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
        $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
    }
    return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array( 'curl' => array( CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, ), ));
$client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';

$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => TRUE,
    'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
}
```

Tutorial says that I need to run my app with command line ( for get verification code). But how run my script without command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php)
it states

> The authorization flow in this example is designed for a command-line application. For information on how to perform authorization in a web application, see Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications.

See [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app):

> 1. Open the [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) in the API Console.
> 2. Click "Create credentials > OAuth client ID."
> 3. Complete the form. Set the application type to Web application. > > Applications that use languages and frameworks like PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, and .NET must specify authorized redirect URIs. The redirect URIs are the endpoints to which the OAuth 2.0 server can send responses. For testing, you can specify URIs that refer to the local machine, such as http://localhost:8080.